# Textview not skipping to next line android

Tags: android, xml

I am a complete beginner in android programming, and I am working with TextViews. I want two TextViews with one on top and one on bottom. But it doesn't work, and I am not sure why. Here is the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So I have the first TextView as fill_parent for width to skip a line, but instead it just takes it out. I can't add a picture as a I just made this account for this question, but it just displays the first TextView and not the next. What is the mistake I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a LinearLayout, you need to set the orientation.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: It goes under LinearLayout. Here is the documentation with all the attributes in LinearLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, here orientation was missing in your code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```